# Database maximum size in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the maximum `.mdf` database size limit in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise ?

Answer (score 5):

16 terabytes per data file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: And you can have a big number of files, so the database size is effectively unlimited.

Comment: @usr: yes, you can have 32,767 files per database, each having 16 TB. Not exactly unlimited, but it should take some time to use it all up.

Comment: You've linked to the Docs for SQL Server 2012. [The answer is still the same in 2008 though](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith: that's what the version selector at the top of the page is for ...

Comment: With that logic every answer would be a link to Google. "That's what search engines are for."

Comment: 16 terabytes/file * 32767 files = 524272 terabytes = **524 petabytes**. Definitely not enough for us, need to look somewhere else.